cant pip install urllib3==1.26.6
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib3==1.26.6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib3==1.26.6

I checked the official website of  https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#history  and found that version 1 is no longer available for download, what should I do?
how can i install urllib3==1.26.6?

I checked the official website of https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/#history and found that version 1 is no longer available for download - it is right here. There must be another problem with pip, for example connection issue to pypi.org usually due to firewall/proxy issues. Is there any output prior to the line that you have copied

It works ! thanks  a  lot  !
